# Blackberry device hang when downloading image online

Tags: multithreading, networking, blackberry

Every time when my apps went to the layout that download image online, the device will hang and need to wait the download finish only can movable.

I did some researched. They recommend download it in another `Thread`. However, I not understand how to implement the download function in another `Thread`.

Here is my code to call the download image function.

```
Main.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (j = 0; j < imagepath.length; j++) {
                    if (!imagepath[j].toString().equals("no picture")
                            && Config_GlobalFunction.isConnected()) {
                        loader = new Util_LazyLoader(imagepath[j],
                                new Util_BitmapDowloadListener() {
                                    public void ImageDownloadCompleted(
                                            Bitmap bmp) {
                                        imagebitmap[j] = bmp;
                                        invalidate();
                                    }
                                });
                        loader.run();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 500, false);
```

And the `lazyloader`

```
public class Util_LazyLoader implements Runnable {
String url = null;
Util_BitmapDowloadListener listener = null;

public Util_LazyLoader(String url, Util_BitmapDowloadListener listener) {
    this.url = url;
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void run() {
    Bitmap bmpImage = getImageFromWeb(url);
    listener.ImageDownloadCompleted(bmpImage);
}

private Bitmap getImageFromWeb(String url) {
    HttpConnection connection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    EncodedImage bitmap;
    byte[] dataArray = null;

    try {
        connection = (HttpConnection) (new ConnectionFactory())
                .getConnection(url + Database_Webservice.ht_params)
                .getConnection();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            inputStream = connection.openDataInputStream();
            dataArray = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inputStream);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    if (dataArray != null) {
        bitmap = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(dataArray, 0,
                dataArray.length);
        return bitmap.getBitmap();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I need help on it as I not familiar in networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the `Util_LazyLoader` is already well written to support background image downloads, because it implements the `Runnable` interface.  You can start the download like this:

```java
Util_LazyLoader loader = 
    new Util_LazyLoader(imagepath[j],
                        new Util_BitmapDowloadListener() {
                            public void ImageDownloadCompleted(final Bitmap bmp) {
                                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        imagebitmap[j] = bmp;
                                        invalidate();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

Thread backgroundWorker = new Thread(loader);
backgroundWorker.start();
```

instead of directly calling the `loader.run()` method yourself.

A `Runnable` class is just one that has a `run()` method.  You give your `Runnable` `loader` object to a new `Thread` and tell it to `start()`.  This will cause that `Thread` to execute the `run()` method in another thread, instead of the UI thread.  As long as you don't run network operations on the UI thread, your app should not appear to the user to be frozen.

**Note:** in your original code, you have this:

```java
Main.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
```

You *probably* don't need that at all.  If that code is being run from the main (UI) thread, then all that's doing is telling the app to invoke that locally-defined `run()` method, **also** on the UI thread.  You do pass a `500` millisecond delay as well.  Maybe you need that (?).  If you just want it to run right away, though, get rid of the code above (`invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { ...`).  Just use the code I posted (at the top of this answer) to create the `backgroundWorker` and then call its `start()` method.

Also, take note of two things in my implementation:

**1.** I used the `UiApplication.invokeLater()` method once the bitmap has been received.  After the network operation completes, the UI must be updated.  But that **should not** be done on the background thread.  So, you create a `Runnable` to run on the background thread, and then once the download is complete, you create another `Runnable` to update the UI:

```java
public void run() {
   imagebitmap[j] = bmp;
   invalidate();
}
```

**2.** Because I create another `Runnable`, and use the `bmp` variable inside that `Runnable`, I must declare it as a `final` parameter.  The compiler requires you to do that.  Another option would be to use the event lock directly, instead of `invokeLater()`:

```java
public void ImageDownloadCompleted(Bitmap bmp) {
    synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
         imagebitmap[j] = bmp;
         invalidate();
    }
}
```

Either should work for you.

Comment: well, it does for listfield but not other field. For example, I got a bitmap field, I display local image then run download in thread. after that, I call `imagebitmap[j] = bmp;
   invalidate();` the bitmapfield's image will not change like in the listfield.

Comment: @AlanLai, I'm wondering if the problem is that you are using the variable `j` to determine which bitmap in `imagebitmap[]` to store.  The `Util_BitmapDowloadListener` probably needs to be passed the index `j`.  Can you post that interface, too?

Comment: @AlanLai, Yep, that's fine, too.  That uses a little less code, but many developers are more familiar with the `invokeLater()` method, so I usually mention that solution first.  Remember, you can **vote** for answers that help you :)